# Change contents of ng-view inside ng-view

Tags: angularjs

Good Day,

I'm trying to create an SPA with Angular.  Here is my index.html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="onlineApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Online</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mystyle.css">
    <base href="/Client/">
</head>
<body ng-controller="mainController">

<div class="container"> <!--- This is the box login  -->
    <div ng-view></div>
</div>

<script src="components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is app.js:

```
var onlineApp = angular.module('onlineApp', ['ngRoute']);

onlineApp.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'Test Message';
});

onlineApp.controller('signupController', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'Sign up Message';
});

onlineApp.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'pages/home.html',
            controller: 'mainController'
        })
        .when('/signup', {
            templateUrl: 'pages/signup.html',
            controller: 'signupController'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });

        // use the HTML 5 History API
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

My problem is:  Inside the contents of the ng-view (home.html), I have a button.  When I click the button, I want to go to a signup page as defined in the route handler and it's not working.  I think the problem is "inside" the ng-view.

EDIT:
Here's a snippet of pages/home.html:

```
<div class="pull-right col-md-4">
    <label class="pull-right col-md-12 create-monthly">Create a Monthly Parker Account</label>
    <a id="btn-create" class="btn btn-primary" href="#signup" >
    Create Account
    </a>
</div>
```

When I click on the button, I want the contents of pages/home.html to be replaced with the contents of pages/signup.html
END EDIT:

All of the examples I see of ng-view being used is when the links are *outside* of the ng-view.

Can I change the contents of ng-view while I'm *inside* the ng-view itself?  Or is there some sort of project that would allow me to do that.

TIA,

coson

Comment: With Angular routing, changing url location does change views. It is not dependent on what level the button is at, merely what state the route points to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just have to change the location of the browser to change the route. i do not really understand your problem, probably you will have to rephrase it or post a little bit more code (from inside your ng-view)

potentially either a link of the form

```
<a href="#/signup">Click me to switch</a>
```

or a manual location change with the $location service (inject it to your controller)

```
$location.path("/signup");
```

should do the job. im not sure what you mean by links inside and outside of ng-view.

Answer (score 0):

The nice thing about using ui-router is that you can treat your view changes as simple page redirects. i.e. you can use an anchor tag to redirect the browser to the specified url and ui-router will catch that before the page refreshes and just update your ui-view without refreshing the page.

```
<a href="#/signup">Click this link to go to signup.</a>
```

Comment: for compatibility reasons you should put an # before the /signup

Comment: Yeah, sometimes I forget that I'm lucky and can expect all my users to have HTML5 compatible browsers :)